# .htaccess 301 redirect inserting query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to organise a simple 301 redirect in my .htaccess file and having some issues.

My current code looks:

```
RewriteRule /contact/ http://www.example.com/connect/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Though when you enter in:
http://www.example.com/contact/

It redirects okay, though places in a query string: 
http://www.example.com.au/connect/?field=contact

Which then makes everything blow-up. I have the 301 on the top of my .htaccess file. I am not sure why this is happening.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: what if you try `RewriteRule http://www.example.com/contact/ http://www.example.com/connect/ [R=301,L,QSA]` ?

Comment: and also try `RewriteRule contact/ http://www.example.com/connect/ [R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: @maxpovver Thank you for your ideas. Both of your solutions didn't really achieve the same result. I think it has to do with the wildcards in the URL. Adding ^/? into the rewrite seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?contact/?$ http://www.example.com/connect/? [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it will discard the original query string from url. If you are u

Comment: Thank you @starkeen your code did the trick. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please also try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/$ http://www.example.com/connect/? [L,R=301]
```